# Change HPLIP appindicator icon

Tags: indicator, hplip, icon-themes

I'm using a HP Printer and the app indicator icon form `hp-systray` doesn't quite fit with the Ubuntu Ambiance theme. I don't like disabling the indicator either.

[image]

So is there a way to change it to a flat monochrome icon like the language indicator in the screenshot? Or is there an icon theme that includes this icon?

And is it Ok to change it? I couldn't find relevant information online and I'm thinking no one tried and shared this because [HP terms](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/terms-of-use.html) say:

> The HP Logo should not be altered in any way.
>
> Do not:
>
> ...
>
> - Change the colors of the logo;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HPLIP panel and toolbox icons can be found at `/usr/share/hplip/data/images/`, where there are folders for a variety of icon sizes. One may change the names of the stock icons by appending ".old" to each file name, then simply copy your desired icons into their respective folders (renaming each according to the original).

[image]

(Note that changing the stock icon names and otherwise editing within these folders will require root privileges. Use `gksu nautilus`, for example, in a terminal; or `sudo` your renaming and copying commands directly. Do be careful when making root changes within system folders.)

Some icon packs *do* contain suitable replacements (*Captiva* is pictured, https://github.com/captiva-project/captiva-icon-theme), but I'm not aware of a ready-made monochrome set. You may be able to create your own with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/support-us/donate/) or [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/donating/).

I'm not aware of HP actively prohibiting home users from customizing the appearance of their Desktop icons. I think their team has been great to provide Linux support; I suspect they'd understand that you're not aiming to undermine their brand or flaunt violation of their policies by bringing aesthetic harmony to your PC.